# Web Scraper: request.get being redirected to different webpage

Tags: python, redirect

I'm trying to write a program that pulls property ID's from an excel spreadsheet, navigates to a webpage based on those ID's where it "web scrapes" the associated property values and imports them back into that same spreadsheet. I apologize in advance I am an extremely novice python (or any language tbh) coder. Here is the code so far:

```
import xlrd
from lxml import html
import requests

class Estimate:
    def importo(self):
    # access excel spreadsheet
    file_location = "S:\Powerdel\Transmission Engineering\Miscellaneous\Estimates\Auto_Estimator\Estimate_Output.xls"
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
    sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

    # import number of columns from spreadsheet
    n = int(sheet.nrows)

    #initalize lists
    id = [0] * (n - 1)
    width = [0] * (n - 1)
    cost = [0] * (n - 1)
    size = [0] * (n - 1)

    # import values from spreadsheet
    for row in range(n-1):
        id[row] = sheet.cell_value(row+1,3)
        width[row] = sheet.cell_value(row+1,1)

    #grab cost from webpage
    #for row in range (n-1):
    name = "http://propaccess.traviscad.org/clientdb/Property.aspx?prop_id={0}" .format(id[0])
    page = requests.get(name)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
    cost[0] = tree.xpath('//div[@id="landDetails"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]/text()')

    print(id[0])
    print(width[4])
    print(n)
    print(cost[0])
    print(name)
    print(tree.text_content().encode('utf-8'))

Estimate().importo()"
```

And the results:

```
337776
492.0
63
[]
http://propaccess.traviscad.org/clientdb/Property.aspx?prop_id=337776
Travis Property Search
  body { text-align: center; padding: 150px; }
  h1 { font-size: 50px; }
  body { font: 20px Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333; }
  #article { display: block; text-align: left; width: 650px; margin: 0 auto; }
  a { color: #dc8100; text-decoration: none; }
  a:hover { color: #333; text-decoration: none; }


Please try again

    Sorry for the inconvenience but your session has either timed out or the server is busy handling other requests. You may visit us on the the following website for information, otherwise please retry your search again shortly:Travis Central Appraisal District Website 
    Click here to reload the property search to try again
```

My problem (for now) is that my request.get is getting redirected from the intended site. Interestingly enough, if I follow the link my program prints out after I run it, I get redirected to the same apology. Buuut, if I navigate to the intended webpage through menu items on the traviscad.org website and thne follow my printed link, boom, correct site.

Like i said, I'm totally new so I have no idea why I'm getting redirected or how to prevent it. If you have any advice, please let me know!

[The desired webpage](http://propaccess.traviscad.org/clientdb/Property.aspx?prop_id=337776)
[The bogus redirect](http://propaccess.traviscad.org/clientdb/customdisplay.htm?aspxerrorpath=/clientdb/Property.aspx)

Comment: When I click on the desired webpage link I get the same result as the bogus redirect, I think the issue might be with acessing the page directly as opposed to through the tabbs

Answer (score 0):

Use mechanize (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/) to simulate an actual browser request to start with.  Then you can traverse the page as if you were browsing to it directly with session details etc.